# Calculating Variance on All Columns and Printing the Results

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, variance

I have a DataFrame that contains around 50 columns and around 1000 rows and all the data in it are Numeric. I'm trying to get some information about the data wherein I'm calculating the Variance of the unique elements in each column expressed as a percentage of the total number of records. As I calculate this, I would like to print that in a human readable format. Here is what I have for that:

```
  def uniqueColumnRatioToTotalNumberOfValues(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.select(df.columns.map(
      column => {
        val distinctCount = countDistinct(col(column))
        val variancePercentage = lit(100) * distinctCount / count(col(column))
        println(s"$column $distinctCount $variancePercentage")
        variancePercentage.alias("column")
      }
    ): _*)
  }
```

But as I ran this, I see the following printed.

```
col1 count(col1) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col1) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col1))
col2 count(col2) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col2) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col2))
col3 count(col3) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col3) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col3))
col4 count(col4) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col4) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col4))
col5 count(col5) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col5) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col5))
col6 count(col6) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col6) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col6))
col7 count(col7) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col7) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col7))
col8 count(col8) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col8) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col8))
col9 count(col9) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col9) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col9))
col10 count(col10) AS `distinctCount` ((100 * count(col10) AS `distinctCount`) / count(col10))
.......
.......
```

How can I get the value out of the results? I would like to have something like this:

```
col1 400 25.4%
col2 3   0.8%
col3 45  2.6%
............
............
............
```

Any clues?

Comment: What do the columns in your expected output represent? specifically the second column.

Comment: All the contents are double datatype

Comment: My question was about the second column in your expected output - how is it calculated?

Comment: val distinctCount = countDistinct(col(column))

Comment: That should be my second column in the expected output